Induction motor with power factor 1/unity
Is it possible to have induction motor with power factor 1/unity under 0.2, 0.4 , 0.6, 0.8 and full load conditions
by switching/adjusting the correcting motor capacitor value
(or by simply switch on and off additional power factor correcting capacitors)
under these load conditions .

Were you expecting more than a trivial "yes" answer--?

Thank you for answer. To achieve Power factor More than 0.9999 by switch on and off (or by adjusting correcting capacitor value) correction Capacitors under mentioned load conditions. I have some doubts. Other answers are very welcome too.

Is the induction motor 3 phase ? or single phase?

Let's consider both motors. If you are sure about 3 phase then write only for 3 phase motors. Thanks

You'll have trouble even measuring 0.9999. For what purpose is this?

OK. Above 0.99 is OK too.

It doesn't make sense to force the PF to be so low under full load motor conditions. Why would you want to do this?

1/unity is 1 written out the long way.
Obviously not possible, but only because you are asking for perfection, some part of the motor will be slightly non-linear, eg (magnetic hysterisis in the stator) and then you will not be able to correct the power factor perfectly.
unless you can find capacitors that are also non-linear in a compensating way.
0.99 is probably possible.

Probably or For Sure If The motor is good quality ?

It depends,  capacitors can correct power factot due to phase angle (cos phi) but they cannot correct harmonic loads.  the bars in the squirrel-cage are slanted to reduce the harmonic load they produce. can they manage 0.99? that seems plausible, but that's driving a fan or other smooth load. If the motor is driving a noisy gearbox then probably not as the gear roughness will also appear as a harmonic load.
